# Is it on topic to ask about technical questions or troubleshooting on a mixer?

Tags: support, topic-scope

I've been posting my issues on a couple of forums, got a friend to try and figure it out, and downloaded the manual to look for some answers, but nothing has been resolved yet.

So, I'm wondering if asking about my problem with the mixer would be considered on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally no, as this site is aimed at designing sound and audio. We have a couple of posts that are in that sort of area, but a forum is much better suited for that sort of thing.

There is an Electronics Stack Exchange, which may be able to help with identifying electrical issues - they have specific requirements as to what you'd need to put in a post, so best read their help pages before posting.